# WebAPI Multiple Conflicting Routes - Authentication Based

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I has a Controller that serves up Events. The Controller provides the route `GET => /Events` that will return an array of Events.

This Controller can serve Events to 3 different types of authentication. `Admin`, `Api`, and `User`.

If the requester is Authenticated as a `User` I want to return the Event object but scoped to the user. e.g.

```
class Event {
 public string Title { get; set; }
}

class EventView {
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public bool RSVPed { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make this possible in my Controller-

```
[RoutePrefix("Events")]
class EventsController {

  [@Authorize(AuthenticationType.Admin, AuthenticationType.Api)]
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() { }

  [@Authorize(AuthenticationType.User)]
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() { }
}
```

Comment: Have one action with all the allowed permissions. within the action you perform desired behavior based on authorized principal. Other wise you have to make the routes unique so as not to conflict with each other.

Comment: I figured that would be the problem. I was hoping the router could someone handle it but that's ok that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have one action with all the allowed permissions. within the action you perform desired behavior based on authorized principal.

```
[RoutePrefix("Events")]
public class EventsController : ApiController {

    [Authorize(AuthenticationType.Admin, AuthenticationType.Api, AuthenticationType.User)]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //Matches GET => /Events
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() { 
        var user = User.Identity;
        if(user.AuthenticationType == AuthenticationType.User) {
            //...User specific code
        } else {
            //...Admin, API specific code
        }
    }

}
```

Other wise you have to make the routes unique so as not to conflict with each other.

```
[RoutePrefix("Events")]
public class EventsController : ApiController {

    [Authorize(AuthenticationType.Admin, AuthenticationType.Api)]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //Matches GET => /Events
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() { 
        //...
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationType.User)]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")] //Matches GET => /Events/12345
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id) { 
        //...
    }
}
```